# Indexing strategy for full text search in a multi-tenant PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, multi-tenant

I have a PostgreSQL database that stores a contact information table (first, last names) for multiple user accounts. Each contact row has a user id column. What would be the most performant way to set up indexes so that users could search for the *first* few letters of the first or last name of their contacts?

I'm aware of conventional b-tree indexing and PG-specific GIN and GiST, but I'm just not sure how they could (or could not) work together such that a user with just a few contacts doesn't have to search all of the contacts before filtering by user_id.

Comment: Might be an interesting candidate for dba.SE (and some formatting to make it easier to read).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the account identifier as the first column of any index you create. This will in effect first narrow down the search to rows belonging to that account. For gist or gin fulltext indexes you will need to install the btree_gist or btree_gin extensions.

If you only need to search for the first letters, the simplest and probably fastest would be to use a regular btree that supports text operations for both columns and do 2 lookups. You'll  need to use the text_pattern_ops opclass to support text prefix queries and lower() the fields to ensure case insensitivity:

```
CREATE INDEX contacts_firstname_idx ON contacts(aid, lower(firstname) text_pattern_ops);
CREATE INDEX contacts_lastname_idx ON contacts(aid, lower(lastname) text_pattern_ops);
```

The query will then look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE aid = 123 AND
    (lower(firstname) LIKE 'an%' OR lower(lastname) LIKE 'an%')
```

Comment: I'm afraid the search requirements may broaden to include things like job title, compnany name etc. So perhaps an additional text column, populated through a trigger or app callback with space separated strings to include in a search from the other columns, could be used to reduce to a single index on user id and that column.

Comment: In that case a full text indexing method would probably be better. If the stop word limitation isn't a problem, the just create an index over the concatenation of fields and use to_tsquery('searchprefix:*'). If you want to be able to search not only from the beginning of words, then look into pg_trgm.